# What specification is used for python's JSON.dumps `strict`?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

**What is the meaning of `strict` in JSON.dumps? Strict to what specification?** The python docs indicate that you must set strict to false in order to parse strings with newlines:

> **If strict is false (True is the default), then control characters will be allowed inside strings. **Control characters in this context are those with character codes in the 0–31 range, including '\t' (tab), '\n', '\r' and '\0'.

However, the JSON specification specifically supports two character escape sequence representations of newlines.

- https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf
- https://www.json.org/json-en.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: "Control characters" and "escape sequences for control characters" are two different things.

Answer (score 3):

`strict` determines whether **literal** control characters are allowed.

The standard mandates that *escape sequences representing* control characters *must* be allowed. It does not mandate that the characters be permitted as literals. That is to say: Strictly, JSON permits the sequence `\n` inside a string; it does *not* allow a newline to be present in place of that two-character sequence.

Comment: For extra clarity, it's the difference between a _newline character_ (ASCII 10), and a _newline escape sequence_ consisting two characters: a backslash character (ASCII 92) and an `n` character (ASCII 110).